# Wordpress + woommerce. Updating stock quantities for items not in the import file

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have an XML file from my supplier with products quantities. But there is a problem when supplier runs out of some product and then they do not include that product in the file anymore. As a consequence after importing XML quantities do not update in my system.
I have tried to talk with my suppliers but they can't help with anything.
So my question is, what would be the easiest way to update quantities to out of stock for missing products?

Comment: Can the supplier provide the empty products with a qty of 0 in the xml?

Comment: I can try to talk with them once again